# What’s a way to append a value to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Appending to array

How do I append to an array in Javascript

Comment: call push().  `var a=[];a.push(1);`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about googling "JavaScript Array Append" for OP.

Comment: My google down or search facility of SO is not working? ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new array.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

And then push values like this

```
fruits.push("Kiwi");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
// create a new array, using the `literals` instead of constructor
var array = [];

// add a value to the last position + 1 (that happens to be array.length) 
array[array.length] = 10;
```

or

```
 // use the push method from Array.
 array.push(10);
```

Also, if you have an Object and you want it to behave like an array (not recommended), you can use

```
Array.prototype.push.call(objectLikeArray, 10);
```